# Forcing an iframe to reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there any way to force an iframe to reload when it goes out of frame?  For example... I have horizontally sliding one page site... there is an iframe that displays a page to play a series of videos.  But when someone slides the site to the next slide, I want the iframe to reload so that the videos stop playing and they are back to the part where they choose a video to play.

I've tried this but oviously it is wrong...

```
window.onblur(function () {
    $('iframe[name="#playerWindow"]').attr("src", $('iframe').attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector syntax is a little off. Try something like below (**untested**):

```
var pWindow = $('#playerWindow');
pWindow.attr('src', pWindow.attr('src'));
```

This is assuming your `iframe` has an ID of `playerWindow`.

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Can you check to see if the `.onblur()` event is even getting fired? Put an alert in there and see if it alerts when you expect it to.

Comment: alert didn't fire... so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You mention that the user will be sliding the slides. What manual action does this require? Is it a click event? If so, is it possible to bind this reset on the click event?

Comment: Not really possible because there are different events that can cause the slide.  Navigation button, previous and next buttons, and the use of arrow keys on the keyboard.  So it will have to be created in some way that would allow the iframe to reload if the page goes out of view.  I'm just not sure how that's possible because Ive never done this before...  However, i have done it using click events and other methods.  In this case that might work only up until the arrow keys being used.

Comment: Well there has to be some central function that performs the slide. Are you using any sort of library for this? All of those different input options should be bound to the same function.

Comment: I dont mean to make this any more difficult than it has to be but...

technically they are not all bound to the same function.  You see, the site is built in section.  First there is a paralax scroller that scrolls 3 sections vertically.  The second (middle) section is another page altogether in its own iframe that scrolls horizontally using completely different code.  And then on 3 of those horizontal pages, there are objects that slide up and down using a third code.  I know... it's complicated...  I'm probably not helping much.